# Index Match Type Mismatch

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to enter the following formula to a range of cells within a macro

```
=INDEX('[Rest Days.xlsx]Sheet1'!$B$3:$B$26,MATCH("*"&A6&"*",'[Rest Days.xlsx]Sheet1'!$E$3:$E$26,0))
```

I keep getting a type mismatch error, I think it's something to do with the "" around the &A6" but can't quite figure it out, Can anyone help me please?

Comment: `""` is just an empty string.  If you want to add an actual quote,  then you need to use it four times: `""""`. (start and beginning of text,  second instance as escape character and third one is the actual quote character.

Comment: Please post the code as is, because we cannot know how you inserted the above formula in VBA code, and the problem might be there.

Comment: Range("G5:G14").Formula = "=INDEX(Nights!$B$2:$B$23,MATCH(" * "&A5&" * ",Nights!$E$2:$E$24,0))"

Comment: `Range("G5:G14").Formula = "=INDEX(Nights!$B$2:$B$23,MATCH("" * ""&A5&"" * "",Nights!$E$2:$E$24,0))"`

Comment: The code has changed a bit from my original post as I've altered my workbook, when I enter the formula in the workbook it works but when I try to do it via the macro I get runtime error 13 and type mismatch.

Comment: so update your post

Comment: Thanks for the advice, Range("G5:G14").Formula = "=INDEX(Nights!$B$2:$B$23,MATCH("" * ""&A5&"" * "",Nights!$E$2:$E$24,0))"  this stops the runtime error but is returning a #NA instead of the result it should.

Comment: well, that has to do with your data! you may want to make a new post and explain /show the necessary details to have people help you out

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to get it working.

```
Range("G5:G14").Formula = "=INDEX(Nights!$B$2:$B$23,MATCH("" * ""&A5&"" * "",Nights!$E$2:$E$24,0))"
```

was suggested but was returning a #NA error.

The #NA was due to the space either side of the * within the quotes.

```
Range("G5:G14").Formula = "=INDEX(Nights!$B$2:$B$23,MATCH(""*""&A5&""*"",Nights!$E$2:$E$24,0))"
```

was the line of code that worked for me.

Thank You.